# Open dialog with a result returned from following a url in a popUp built with magnificPopup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, magnific-popup

My popup is opened successfully using this jquery code

```
<html>
<head>
    <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/0.9.9/magnific-popup.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/0.9.9/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="someid">Open popup</button>

<script>
    $('#someid').magnificPopup({
                                          items: {
                                              src:  
                                                    '<div class="white-popup"><br>\
                                                    <a href="**someUrl**">Click</a>',

                                              type: 'inline'
                                          }
                           });  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How to open a dialog with a result returned from following a url ("someUrl" above) in a popUp built with magnificPopup?
Tried embeeding javascript function call into 'src' key of magnificPopup, however it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to open a webpage inside the magnific popup, use the type Ajax. Your code just links to a URL.

One other thing you can do is perform an ajax get and open the popup after the response. Make the response result of the ajax response as the data in your popup.

Comment: Thanks. However, there are several links inside a popup. The result depends on user choice.

Comment: Then use my second option. Bind an ajax get/post to the user click and update the popup content after the response.